# Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, preloader

I try to do preloder in Flex for my project written in Flash.
I make this with the help of this site 
[link text](http://www.flexer.info/2008/02/07/very-first-flex-preloader-customization/)
 My Flash project have next source in main class called Game

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);

private function keyDown(event:KeyboardEvent) {
   if (event.keyCode == 81 && q_was_push == false) q_was_push = true;
   if (event.keyCode == 81) press_q = true;
   if (event.keyCode == 65) press_a = true;
   if (event.keyCode == 83) press_s = true;
   if (event.keyCode == 32) press_space = true;
} ...
```

When I take new swf file maked by Flex, I have error 
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Game()

if I comment

```
//stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
//stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);
```

Flex application work but Flash application does not react to button presses

Please how I can make preloader and work buttons together

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `stage` property will be null until a display object is added to the display list. Listen to the [addedToStage](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#event:addedToStage) event and add the key listeners from there.

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
{
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you need access to the stage, have the Class listen for it/check for it in the constructor, and have your init function be the handler.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author Brian Hodge
     */
    public class SomeClass extends Sprite
    {

        public function SomeClass() 
        {
            if (stage) _init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _init);
        }
        private function _init(e:Event = null):void
        {
            //You may now access the stage property of the DisplayObject.
            stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE);
        }
  }

}
```